# c# safe call windows form static

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

is it possile to call windows forms safe in multithreaded application with static?
or how can i create an instance for this:

the safe call of windows form in multithreaded application:

```
    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);   
    private void AddItemListBox2(string text)
    {
        if (this.listBox2.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(AddItemListBox2);
            this.listBox2.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.listBox2.Items.Add(text);
        }
    }
```

the function that try to call the AddItemListBox2(string text):

```
public static void ManageClient(string ipAddress, string macAddress, string machineName, bool Add)
    {
        bool isClient = false;

        using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionStringStatic()))
        using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT ID FROM tbl_Clients WHERE ipAddress = '" + ipAddress + "' AND macAddress = '" + macAddress + "' AND machineName = '" + machineName + "';";
            connection.Open();
            string id = "";
            try
            {
                OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                isClient = true;
                while (dr.Read())  
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        id = dr.GetValue(i).ToString();
                    }                        
                }
                if (isClient == true)
                {
                    AddItemListBox2("Dieser Client existiert ereits - Client ID: " + id + "."); // this make a error because of the static^^
                }
            }
            catch (OleDbException ox)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (isClient == false && Add == true)
                {
                    AddClient(ipAddress, macAddress, machineName);
                }
            }

        }  
    }
```

how is it possible to call the AddItemListBox2(string text) from a static function ?

Comment: No you cannot. Not without an instance to call this method on. And you don't seem to have any in your static method.

Comment: @nvoigt no idon't have an instance...how can i create one ?

Comment: You already have an instance or you would not see your form. Why is the method static in the first place, if you need to access the instance?

Comment: @nvoigt the function is static because of a lot other function, nothing will work any more if i remove the static - then i got 47 errors....

Comment: @nvoigt but how can i create an instance ?